# Android Studio 2.0 en ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle

Hola quisiera me pudieran ayudar con este error que me aparece en android studio 2.2 en ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Error:Process 'command '/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2** [image: Este es el error que me sale]

Comment: Este error está relacionado con Gradle. Podrías dar más información con respecto a esto? Fichero de configuración de Gradle, Version....Todo lo que esté relacionado con Gradle.

Comment: Seria bueno si subes tu archivo ***.grade*** para poder verificarlo, 2, no agregaste una libreria nueva?

Comment: El archivo "build.gradle".